# How to add constraint to SQL Server 2008 using constraint dialog?

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2008, sql-server-2008

How do you manually define a constraint in SQL Server 2008 dialog box? I want to add a constraint that when I add a new record if its already there don't add it. My table is structured so that

`AdvCatJoinID` is my primary key, `CatID` is the key from the `Category` table, and `AliasID` is the primary key from the alias table, I want the constraint to be that if the `CatID` and `AliasID` already exist in the table as a pair then don't add a new record (as it already exists), how to?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Step 1:**

In the SQL Server Object Explorer, find your database and table that you want to put the constraint on, and navigate to the `Indexes` subnode, and right-click, choose `New Index`:

[image]

**Step 2:**

In the dialog box that pops up, define your unique index:

- give it a name of your choosing
- make sure the `[ X ]  Unique` checkbox is checked
- click on the `[ Add ]` button twice to add your two columns to the index

[image]

When you've done those two steps, you now have a **unique index** on the `(CatID, AliasID)` combination and no pair of those two values can exist more than once in your table.

Answer (score 2):

Do you really need the `AdvCatJoinID` column? Usually for these association tables I just have a composite primary key on the 2 foreign key columns. That enforces the unique aspect.

Otherwise to do it in SSMS you need to go through the "Indexes/Keys" dialogue (NOT the constraints one) and configure a new Unique Index with both columns selected. You access this dialogue after right clicking the table and selecting "Design" then right clicking the table designer grid.

To create a unique constraint rather than unique index you would choose the option "Unique Key" but there is no practical difference netween the two.

Comment: "...no practical difference..." - except for the ability for a foreign key constraint to reference a unique constraint, but not a unique index.

Comment: @Damien - There is no such difference This works fine `create table t(c int) go create unique index ix on t(c) go create table t2 (c int references t(c))`. There might be some differences like not being able to add included columns to an index backing up a unique constraint though actually.

Comment: I'm sure I found a difference in this behaviour in the past, but have just retested against 2008 and 2000, and you're right. I wonder what I was thinking of?

Comment: @Damien - I've got a vague feeling that using an index rather than a constraint gives you more flexibility actually but I can't point to any specifics apart from possibly included columns.